# Update Interests table with a list of values passed from my C# application

Tags: .net, database, c#-2.0

The Interests table by definition is:
Column         Type        Value
ID             varchar(10) UniqueId of the contact
Interest1      bit         1 if customer has chosen the interest field 0 if not!
Interest2      bit  
Interest3      bit
...
Interest37

This is a DotNet 2.0 application from where I need to update the User record in the Interests table upon the click of the Update button.

The values of the interests are dependant on the values from 3 CheckBoxList.

Answer (score 0):

you can create stored procedure in your database and call it in your button event handler and pass values to that.